# Converting SQL Server Create script to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server Create Script. Can anyone help me convert this to MySQL.

I'm not sure what the bit defining the Primary Key is doing.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webdb`.`UserSessions`(
UniqueID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
UserID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
TokenExpires DATETIME NOT NULL,
LastSeen DATETIME NOT NULL,
LoggedOut bit NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EndedSessions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
UniqueID ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webdb`.`UserSessions`
(
    UniqueID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    UserID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    TokenExpires DATETIME NOT NULL,
    LastSeen DATETIME NOT NULL,
    LoggedOut bit NOT NULL
);
```